# Changing the color of the canvas with javascript undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to change the color of the canvas to red (#FF0000) in the console. The html element is displayed below.

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="858" height="754"></canvas> == $0
```

Originally, tried the code below, the canvas changed for a tenth of a second or so, and then it went back to its origial white color and resulted in an undefined message in the console.

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1500, 1000);
```

I then hovered my mouse over the == $0 thing and it said I could reference that element using $0. My attempt at solving the problem now is below.

```
var ctx = $0.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1500, 1000);
```

Does anyone know how I should solve this problem, and correctly change the color of the canvas??

edit: i recently tried the code below, and the canvas flashes between red and white every time i resize my browser, but after i stop resizing it, the color is back to white.

```
$0.style.background = 'red'
```

Comment: Please provide code for ```the canvas changed for a tenth of a second or so, and then it went back to its origial white color and resulted in an undefined message```

Comment: that code was already provided above, it is the second code block

Comment: @Wieniawski your code to change the canvas background is correct, there is probably some function or listener running that's reseting the background color

Comment: @Zoilo Granda do you know if i could disable that function or listener?

Comment: @Wieniawski yes but you need to check your code to see what else is running, and post some code here